# Exposed filter selectbox dropdown for a textfield

Tags: 7, views

I have a textfield for one of my content types and there are many unique results for it. I am trying to create a View of this content type of this textfield as an Exposed Filter with a list of all the unique results from this textfield. Views by default only gives you a textbox for you to search through these results, but if you don't know what to look for, it doesn't work too well.

- How would I expose this textfield of all the unique results in a selectbox in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue sometime ago and finally the only way to display all the values from a field in a dropdown filter seems to be the Drupal taxonomy. The Grouped flters option is fine but you need to enter all the values manually in the table (Label/value) and I think this is not what you are looking for.

If you can clone your Text field in a Term reference field (Taxonomy vocabulary), you should be able to create a dropdown filter in Views, based on this new Taxonomy field, with autocomplete or dropdown option for filter display. Then, each time a new term is created in the vocabulary, it will be suggested in the dropdown menu.

It was my option but maybe someone can suggest a way to display all field values in a filter, even if it is not a vocabulary. I would be really interested in that solution, anyway.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Grouped filters** of exposed filters to set unique results for select box in a views. Please see the screenshot given below:

[image: Grouped filters example to convert textfield to dropdown]

Comment: The thing is that my field is a custom field, but it acts like a textfield storing the same type of data. I tried to do the same thing, but I dont see the same options: http://prntscr.com/bgb7wn

Comment: In the attached screenshot(prntscr.com/bgb7wn), I can see the option of grouped filters with ability to add options for the field.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to filter my view with a bunch of offices, but these offices were in a custom made field formatted in json. I had to clean up the field by running it through views_php with preg_replace() to get it ready for processing.

Once my data is formatted correctly for js consumption. I concatenate all of these offices together into a gigantic array. From there I run through this array to detect duplicates and end up with a results array of unique results.

Then I add these unique results into an appended

[image]

```
//If needed run the field through a views_php field to prepare it for processing. Separate each entry with a comma so you can split it via js.

a = jQuery(".views-field-php em").text();
b = a.split(',');

var results = []; //Create an empty results array variable to be filled


jQuery.each(b, function(index, value) { //Run through "each" value and put it into results array

  if ((jQuery.inArray(value, results) == -1) && value != '') { //Does the value exist in the results array? If not do the following
    results.push(value); //Adds the value to the results array
  }

});

results = results.sort(); //Sort all the arrays alphabetically

//Add in the <select element into the page
jQuery("#edit-field-role-offices-wrapper").append('<select id="filter-off"><option>Filter by Office</option></select>');

//Add the <option elements according to EACH array value in results
results.forEach(function(z) {
  jQuery("#filter-off").append('<option value="' +z+ '">' +z+ '</option>');
});

//When selecting an item, copy that value into the textfield above and then hit the submit button
jQuery("#filter-off").live("change", function() {
  jQuery("#edit-field-role-offices").val(this.value);
  jQuery("#edit-submit-yearbook").click();
});
```